# Can't logout from Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, stackexchange.com, logout

I can successfully LogIn and LogOut for Stack Exchange-sites like Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux.

But when I open http://stackexchange.com, I found me as logged-in, so when I try to logout, I'm getting the following error:

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

### Here is scenario:

1. **Found logged in on http://stackexchange.com:**

   [image: screen-1]
2. **Tried to log-out:**

   [image: screen-2]
3. **Clicking on log-out buttion:**

   [image]
4. **Getting following Error:**

   [image]

My problem is that I can't logout **only from stackexchange.com.** (I have been trying to logout for 2 days.)

What should/can I do?

---

**Finally I deleted/cleared all data (i.e history,cookies,form-data etc.) on my Opera web browser.
Now I can successfully LogIn as well as Logout from stackexchange.**

Comment: I can't reproduce. How are you trying to logout?

Comment: @Oded I clarified steps by editing in question.

Comment: Same steps I took. No repro.

Comment: @Oded What do you mean by reproduce?

Comment: Reproduce the bug. I can't manage to get an error page, following the same steps. I don't see an error message.

Comment: I can log out successfully too, as @Oded. Any additional settings or extensions in your browser?

Comment: You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave.

Comment: @Oded no hint in the server error log?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - no. Nada. Zilch.

Comment: You can always delete all cookies for the stackexchange.com domain - could be a corrupt cookie there.

Comment: I have a similar issue where clicking the log out link simply does nothing and I remain logged in. Occasionally I am randomly logged out five minutes later, usually not.