# Logging out of https://stackexchange.com fails when trying to clear login credentials

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, logout, ssl

So I was trying to reproduce this: [Can't logout from Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236409/cant-logout-from-stack-exchange)

No luck, but I noticed a few other things:

1. Logging out leaves you at `https://stackexchange.com`
2. Logging back in also leaves you at the secure site
3. Trying to log out a second time *while still viewing the HTTPS site* will fall apart when trying to clear global credentials:

[image: the page was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from...]

Comment: It is not a browser dependend bug: repro-ed on IE11 (win7/x64) (warning dialog: Only secure content is displayed)

Comment: Taking a look at this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced the issue and have checked in a fix. It will be live in the next production release of stackexchange.com (> rev `2014.7.15.1073`).